# Using stored numbers in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Here's the piece of code that's giving me trouble:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
With Worksheets("Rent Roll")
lastRow = Worksheets("Summary").Range("NUM_UNITS").Value
.Range("A1:A" & lastRow + 25).EntireRow.Hidden = False
.Range("A" & lastRow + 26 & ":A526").EntireRow.Hidden = True
.Range("S3").Formula = "=COUNTIF(""J26:J"" & lastRow + 25,""A"")"
```

Specifically its the last line of the code. Can you not used the stored number from lastRow when changing a cells formula?

Comment: Use source cell address in the formula instead of its value stored in the variable. You need to use additional INDIRECT() function to convert the string address you built to the range address in the COUNTIF() first argument.

Comment: @Akina Could you go into more detail if you have time? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelFroboese, if you are trying LastRow like this `=COUNTIF(C3:lastrow+2)` then it should be written like this,, `"=CountIf(C3:" & Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 2, 3).Address & ")"`

Comment: `.Range("S3").Formula = "=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""J26:J"" & Summary!NUM_UNITS),""A"")"`.

Comment: Looks like your quotes are not in the right spot: `.Range("S3").Formula = "=COUNTIF(J26:J" & lastRow + 25 & ",""A"")"`